# Downloading Kaggle files in Python

Tags: python, csv, kaggle

My question is a continuation of: [documentation for Kaggle API *within* python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55934733/documentation-for-kaggle-api-within-python).

So, I download a dataset with the Kaggle API:

```py
api.dataset_download_files('berkeleyearth/climate-change-earth-surface-temperature-data',
                           path='datasets/kaggle', unzip=True)
```

Is there a way to fetch the name of the downloaded csv files? Or do I have to make sure I download (and unzip) the files in a dedicated folder that I should then browse?

Comment: Some unofficial documentation here: [https://technowhisp.com/kaggle-api-python-documentation/](https://technowhisp.com/kaggle-api-python-documentation/)

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted! :)
```python
file_list = api.dataset_list_files('berkeleyearth/climate-change-earth-surface-temperature-data').files
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation here: https://technowhisp.com/kaggle-api-python-documentation/

> **5.2 Listing dataset files**
>
> `api.dataset_list_files('avenn98/world-of-warcraft-demographics').files`

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install kaggle
```

then authenticate

```
Authenticating With API Server

 from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi
 api = KaggleApi()
 api.authenticate()
Downloading Datasets
```

and download

```
# Download all files of a dataset
# Signature: dataset_download_files(dataset, path=None, force=False, quiet=True, unzip=False)
api.dataset_download_files('avenn98/world-of-warcraft-demographics')

# downoad single file
#Signature: dataset_download_file(dataset, file_name, path=None, force=False, quiet=True)
api.dataset_download_file('avenn98/world-of-warcraft-demographics','WoW Demographics.csv')
```