# How can i import dataset from kaggle directly into my Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset, kaggle

I've worked with a couple of datasets on Kaggle but every time I download the data and then import it to my notebook. I'm trying to upload it directly via URL but in vain.

I've searched for a few ways, but not getting how they work.
(link to that is mentioned)
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69216137/import-csv-from-kaggle-url-into-a-pandas-dataframe](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

[Kaggle datasets into jupyter notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52681196/kaggle-datasets-into-jupyter-notebook)

looking for help with either explaining these ways or telling me any other.
Thanks in advance...